How do I get custom widgets to render in Visual Studio 2022 design tool with .NET Android?
I'm working on an Android app written in C# using the new .NET Android stuff (not Xamarin.Android). Note this is not MAUI (MAUI is to Xamarin.Forms as .NET Android is to Xamarin.Android). I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (17.9.7), targeting .NET 8.0 and Android API 34.
I've got a custom widget class that derives from an existing widget (let's say TextView for the sake of example).
It all works fine at runtime. My problem is that, in the preview in the design tool, I get a "Custom controls disabled. There was an internal issue with the rendering process." and my widget is drawn as a grey box.
Here is the widget class from my trivial test case:
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;

namespace CustomWidgetTest
{
    public class MyTextView : TextView
    {
        public MyTextView(Context? context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public MyTextView(Context? context, IAttributeSet? attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        public MyTextView(Context? context, IAttributeSet? attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
        }

        public MyTextView(Context? context, IAttributeSet? attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        {
        }

        protected MyTextView(nint javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }
    }
}

Here is the layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="@string/app_text"
    />
    <CustomWidgetTest.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="@string/app_text"
    />
</LinearLayout>

And here is what I see in the designer preview:

What I'd expect to see in this case is a second identical "Hello, Android!" line just below the first one.
Things I have tried that did not fix the problem:

Adding an attribute like [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
Pressing the Re-enable button
Closing and re-opening Visual Studio
Removing my bin, obj and .vs folder and their contents.
Moving MyTextView into a separate project within the same solution and referencing it.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Links to statements from Microsoft indicating that they powerfully don't care about the design tool will be accepted with grim resignation. Suggestions of the form "just use Android Studio and Kotlin" will be met with "I'd love to, but [external constraints]."
